# Combine and Sum Based on Multpile Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set with 3 columns A, B, C. A and B and labels (product type and city, for example) with column C as numerical data.

I have used the following to combine and sum either A or B for C:

```
Sub combineandsum1()
'Update 20130829
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Dic As Variant
Dim arr As Variant
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
arr = WorkRng.Value
For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    Dic(arr(i, 1)) = Dic(arr(i, 1)) + arr(i, 2)
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
WorkRng.ClearContents
WorkRng.Range("A1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.keys)
WorkRng.Range("B1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.items)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But that only works for a single criteria. How can I alter this macro so it reads:

If A is a duplicate in column A AND B is a duplicate in column B, then combine and sum C.

Having a real brainfart here, could use the help. Thanks!

Comment: SUMIFS() does not work for you?

Comment: Or a Pivot Table?